# HierarchyRequestError when modifying DOM in Windows Metro application

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm building a Windows Metro application using Javascript and HTML and it crashes with a `HierarchyRequestError`:

```
Exception was thrown but not handled in user code at line 11, column 9 in ms-appx://21706d2f-b81e-47ef-9ebb-37de36c7a258/js/default.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: HierarchyRequestError
```

At the line that throws the error I'm doing some simple DOM manipulation and try to insert a node I created into the document:

```
function insertData(hnode) {
    document.querySelector('#datanode').appendChild(hnode);
}
```

Why would this fail with such an error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `HierarchyRequestError` is thrown when you try to insert `undefined`, or some other invalid value, into the DOM.

In the function in the question, `hnode` is probably `undefined`, for example because `insertData()` was called without parameters.

To debug a situation like this and find out which call to `insertData()` is the problem, a conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio can be used. If you set a breakpoint, right-click on it and choose *"Condition..."*. A condition like `hnode === undefined` can be used to break on just the interesting cases.

Comment: more like typeof hnode === 'undefined'

Comment: @eomeroff: That would work too, but doesn't really make a difference.